# Tool for making Installer on MacOS

Tags: macos, installation

I am finding a way to making an installer for my program on **MacOS**, which has the capability to creating a good GUI installer and doing something pre and post installation like having the program run on startup, ...
(like **InnoSetup** on Windows http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). I have found such a tool like this that is **InstallBuilder** https://installbuilder.bitrock.com/ but it is not free (and on my view has a high price). Does anybody knows a suitable tool for me?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you need to create an installation package or distribution for Mac OS X 10.5 or later, [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) is the powerful and flexible solution.

Comment: Hi Ivanov, using Packages how can I run a preinstallation script then grab the exit code of the script and display a corresponding message (Eg: write a preinstallation script to stop another app, if exit code = 1 then display message like 'Cannot stop the ... app'?

Comment: You are able to do everything you want in your shell script, I may help by providing you with example, but this is yet another question you would need to post. if the answer on the original question satisfy you, consider accepting it. Accepting Answers: [How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)